# middle toggle line not disappearing properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a toggle button on my practice site. On click, it makes some transition and makes cross or X. I am using some CSS to make a cross with top and bottom lines and by hiding middle one. The problem is after transitions the middle line is not hiding and making some * like shape.

I tried visibility: none on middle one but it makes whole toggle button visible none.

I also tried by changing the middle line background color same as a cover background color but this is also not working.

```css
header nav.small-menu {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  opacity: .9;
  z-index: 2;
}

header nav.small-menu .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: .9rem;
  left: 2rem;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: .8s;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .navigation .toggle {
  background: var(--primary-white);
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 73rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

header .navigation .togglesmall {
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 2.5rem;
  left: 73rem;
  background: var(--primary-blue);
}

header .navigation .togglesmall::before,
header .navigation .togglesmall::after {
  background: var(--primary-blue);
}

header .navigation .toggle::before,
header .navigation .toggle::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: var(--primary-white);
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .navigation .toggle::before {
  top: -14px;
}

header .navigation .toggle::after {
  top: 14px;
}

header .navigation .toggle.active::before {
  background: var(--primary-white);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

header .navigation .toggle.active::after {
  background: var(--primary-white);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

header .navigation .overlay {
  background: var(--primary-blue);
  position: fixed;
  top: 28px;
  right: 53px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.7;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .navigation .overlay.active {
  transform: scale(100, 100);
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .navigation .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

header .navigation .menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <div class="logo">

      </div>
      <div class="main-menu">
        <div class="toggle"></div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="menu">

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
      $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
      $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
      $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
    });
  });


  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      $('nav').removeClass('small-menu');
      $('.navigation .main-menu .toggle').removeClass('togglesmall');
    } else {
      $('nav').addClass('small-menu');
      $('.navigation .main-menu .toggle').addClass('togglesmall');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding css while active class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
    $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
    $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
  });
});


$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('nav').removeClass('small-menu');
    $('.navigation .main-menu .toggle').removeClass('togglesmall');
  } else {
    $('nav').addClass('small-menu');
    $('.navigation .main-menu .toggle').addClass('togglesmall');
  }
});
```

```css
body{background: #000;}
header nav.small-menu {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  opacity: .9;
  z-index: 2;
}

header nav.small-menu .logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: .9rem;
  left: 2rem;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: .8s;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .navigation .toggle {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 3rem;
  left: 73rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

header .navigation .togglesmall {
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 2.5rem;
  left: 73rem;
  background: var(--primary-blue);
}

header .navigation .togglesmall::before,
header .navigation .togglesmall::after {
  background: var(--primary-blue);
}

header .navigation .toggle::before,
header .navigation .toggle::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .navigation .toggle::before {
  top: -14px;
}

header .navigation .toggle::after {
  top: 14px;
}

header .navigation .toggle.active::before {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

header .navigation .toggle.active::after {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

header .navigation .overlay {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 28px;
  right: 53px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .navigation .overlay.active {
  transform: scale(100, 100);
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .navigation .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

header .navigation .menu.active {
  visibility: visible;
}

header .navigation .toggle.active {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
}

 .overlay.active { opacity: .7; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class="main-menu">
      <div class="toggle"></div>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="menu">

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: this will work on a white background and white toggle color. If you change either background color or toggle color then it is still visible.

Comment: check the updated answer will work with different color as well.

Comment: add some opacity to
header .navigation .overlay.active {
opacity:  .7;
}

Comment: in that case you need == background: transparent; Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

on click you just have to remove box-shadow property from css class 
header .navigation .toggle and it will work.

So after you click the menu, inspect the element and just uncheck box-shadow property to check the result.

Comment: this will work on a white background and white toggle color. If you change either background color or toggle color then it is still visible

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('.toggle').toggleClass('active');
        $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
        $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
    });
});


$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
        $('nav').removeClass('small-menu');
        $('.navigation .main-menu .toggle').removeClass('togglesmall');
    }
    else{
        $('nav').addClass('small-menu');
        $('.navigation .main-menu .toggle').addClass('togglesmall');
    }
});
```

```css
header nav.small-menu{
                background: #fff;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5rem;
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
                opacity: .9;
                z-index: 2;
                }

                header nav.small-menu .logo{
                position: absolute;
                top: .9rem;
                left: 2rem;
                height: 80px;
                width: 100px;
                transition: .8s;
                z-index: 2;
                }

                header .navigation .toggle{
                background: var(--primary-white);
                position: absolute;
                width: 35px;
                height: 4px;
                top: 3rem;
                left: 73rem;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
                transition: all .5s ease-out;
                cursor: pointer;
                z-index: 1;
                transition: 0.3s linear;
                }

                header .navigation .toggle.active{
                box-shadow: none;
                transition: 0.3s linear;
                }    

                header .navigation .togglesmall{
                width: 35px;
                height: 4px;
                top: 2.5rem;
                left: 73rem;
                background: var(--primary-blue);
                }

                header .navigation .togglesmall::before,
                header .navigation .togglesmall::after{
                background: var(--primary-blue);
                }

                header .navigation .toggle::before,
                header .navigation .toggle::after{
                position: absolute;
                content: '';
                background: var(--primary-white);
                width: 35px;
                height: 4px;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
                transition: all .5s ease-out;
                cursor: pointer;
                }

                header .navigation .toggle::before{
                top: -14px;
                }

                header .navigation .toggle::after{
                top: 14px;
                }

                header .navigation .toggle.active::before{
                background: var(--primary-white);
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
                top: 0;
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                z-index: 1;
                }

                header .navigation .toggle.active::after{
                background: var(--primary-white);
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
                top: 0;
                transform: rotate(135deg);
                z-index: 1;
                }

                header .navigation .overlay{
                background: var(--primary-blue);
                position: fixed;
                top: 28px;
                right: 53px;
                width: 45px;
                height: 45px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                transition: all .5s ease-out;
                opacity: 0.7;
                visibility: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
                }

                header .navigation .overlay.active{
                transform: scale(100, 100);
                visibility: visible;
                cursor: pointer;
                }

                header .navigation .menu{
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
                visibility: hidden;
                }

                header .navigation .menu.active{
                visibility: visible;
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <div class="logo">

            </div>
            <div class="main-menu">
                <div class="toggle"></div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="menu">

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: this will work on a white background and white toggle color. If you change either background color or toggle color then it is still visible